# Setting the position of a sprite not working in SFML/Box2D

Tags: c++, box2d, sfml

I'm trying to get physics working in SFML using Box2D, but for some reason I can't set the position of my sprite in my class.

I created a TestBox for my game, basically just a box that has physics, but it doesn't seem to be working. I am able to set the position of the box in my class constructor, but not in the update function I created.

So onto the code:

TestBox.h:

```
#pragma once
#include<Box2D/Box2D.h>
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include<string>
#include<iostream>
class TestBox : public sf:: Drawable
{
public:
    TestBox(b2World *world, std::string texturePath, float x, float y, float w, float h);

    void update();

    b2Body *getBody() { return body; }
    b2Fixture *getFixture() { return fixture; }
private:
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget &target, sf::RenderStates states) const;
    b2Body *body = nullptr;
    b2Fixture *fixture = nullptr;

    sf::Texture texture;
    sf::Sprite boxSprite;
};
```

TestBox.cpp:

```
#include "TestBox.h"

TestBox::TestBox(b2World *world, std::string texturePath, float x, float y, float w, float h) {
    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.Set(x, y);
    body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

    b2PolygonShape boxShape;
    boxShape.SetAsBox(w / 2.0f, h / 2.0f);

    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = &boxShape;
    fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.3f;

    fixture = body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);

    texture.loadFromFile(texturePath.c_str());
    boxSprite.setTexture(texture);
    boxSprite.setOrigin(16.f, 16.f);
    boxSprite.setPosition(30.0f * body->GetPosition().x, 30.0f * body->GetPosition().y);
    boxSprite.setRotation(body->GetAngle() * 180 / b2_pi);
}

void TestBox::update() {
    std::cout << boxSprite.getPosition().x << ", " << boxSprite.getPosition().y << std::endl;
    boxSprite.setPosition(30.0f * body->GetPosition().x, 30.0f * body->GetPosition().y);
    boxSprite.setRotation(body->GetAngle() * 180 / b2_pi);
}

void TestBox::draw(sf::RenderTarget &target, sf::RenderStates states) const {
    target.draw(boxSprite, states);
}
```

So, I've tried to narrow down my problem as much as possible, and rule as much as I could out. Here is what I found:

- I am able to set the position in the constructor, this works fine.
- I have been checking the position of the Box2D body, the position of that changes fine.
- I have checked the math:

  30.0f * body->GetPosition().x

  30.0f * body->GetPosition().y

  this is accurate and works fine.
- The update function does run, it prints normally.
- The result of printing the position is always the start position

Let me know if I left out any information you could need.

Comment: Do you update the box2d world in your game loop?

Comment: I do, with the step function right? If I print out the position of the box it does in fact change, even if the position of the sprite does not.

Comment: Is there a reason why the body should move in the physics world? Have you set a gravity vector in the box2d world?Also, it's unlikely, but it's possible that the body is created ontop of a static object in the physics world what prevents the TestBox to move.

Comment: The thing is- the box DOES move, it's a problem with setting the position of the SFML sprtie, like I said, if I print the position of the dynamic box, it moves, it's just the sprite position that isn't moving. I'm 90% sure this is an SFML range problem, I think that the sprite is going out of range in rendering I just don't understand where.

Comment: Remove the `const` from `TestBox::draw` and try again

Comment: Yeah, that results in the error: `'TestBox': cannot instantiate abstract class`

Comment: Make sure the signatures of all methods match up and every method is defined (remove `const` in header **and** source file)

Comment: I did do that. If you look at the [`sf::Drawable` documentation](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Drawable.php) you can see in their example that they do use `const` in their method definition.

Comment: Also, I'm not changing the sprite position in the draw function I'm changing it in the update function. The position of the sprite does not change at all, I have printed it out and it always starts at the same position.

Comment: The draw function needs to be const since it's derived from `sf::Drawables`. As for the issue, you need to provide a complete, compilable and minimal example. It has to be some error in your code, but with the provided code, I can't find it.

Comment: I have found the error, the vector I was using was not a pointer vector.